# How to listen on JWT token expiration in a react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have a react app alogside with a node backend. After the user logs in successfully a JWT token is created in the backend and set back to the frontend where it is stored in localStorage. I created a custom hook responsible for checking if the token in localstorage is still valid whenever the hook is called.

The thing is that the hook is called only when the page refreshes (when the component is re-mounted) the ideal scenario is that whenever the token expired my react app ''listens'' and automatically send the user back to the login page. Currently, if I'm logged in and the token expires I'm still inside the app and I'm sent back to the login page only if I refresh the page (because that's when my custom hook gets called and checks whether the token in local storage is valid or not.

How should I go about that? Is there something like a observer or smth that I can use to be always ''checking'' the token and whenever it isn't valid anymore the user gets logged out and presented with the login page?

Comment: Your app should be checking for `401` unauthorized error response codes on the api calls. The moment you get a `401` response status code on any of the api, you should redirect the user to login page. Have a look at this [link](https://www.bigbinary.com/react-best-practices/logout-on-401), it will give you a better idea

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303694/reactjs-logout-redirect-user-on-failed-api-call) might also help

Comment: How about you get the expiration time and set a `setTimeout()` to fetch new token few minutes before expiration? Or redirect to login page?

Comment: Yes, I thought about the 401 status code approach. I have seen web sites that log us out without having to make an api call, I wanted the same experience in my app, I have no idea how to implement that though. If I dont come up with anything else the 401 status code will be the only way I can think of.